# Protractor: commands in afterLaunch don't run

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to send an email out with results after tests have finished running.
When I put the sendgrid call in the onComplete section, then the email sends.  However, the report is empty since it hasn't finished saving.

If I put the sendgrid call into the afterLaunch section, then the file is saved.  However, it doesn't seem to run the sendgrid command.

This is the config that I am using:

```
var HtmlReporter = require ('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
var browser = "chrome";
var environment = "dev";
var pname = "";
var pversion = "";
var dname = "";
var selenium_address = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
var folder_name = (new Date()).toString().split(' ').splice(0,3).join('');
var report_folder = "./test/e2e/reports/" + folder_name + "_" + browser +   "_" + environment + "/";
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
  savePath: report_folder,
  takeScreenshots: false,
  cleanDestination: true,
  fileName: 'CE_Smoketest'
});

function test_function() {
   var report = report_folder + 'CE_Smoketest.html'
   var sendgrid = require('sendgrid')('xxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx');
   var email = new sendgrid.Email();
   email.addTo("destination@mail.com");
   email.setFrom("Smoketest@mail.com");
   email.setSubject("Smoketest");
   email.setHtml("Smoketest results");
   email.addFile({filename: report});
   sendgrid.send(email);
}

exports.config = {
//appium setup
seleniumAddress: selenium_address,
multiCapabilities: [
{
    'browserName' : browser,
    platformName : pname,
    platformVersion : pversion,
    deviceName: dname
}
],

getPageTimeout: 50000,
allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000,
  isVerbose: true
},

onPrepare: function() {

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
      },
onComplete: function(exitCode) {
    test_function();

},
afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
    test_function();
}
}
```

Any ideas as to why afterLaunch doesn't send the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suresh is right, you must return a promise if you want asynchronous code to be executed before the program exits

Try this:

1- Declare new var

```
var q = require('q');
```

2- Refactor your afterLaunch

```
afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
  return q.fcall(function () {
     test_function();
  }).delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adolfo, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In afterLaunch methods, Webdriver instance have been shutdow(Not available). That's you code will get executed. Check description of afterLaunch() method below:

```
/**
* A callback function called once all tests have finished running and
* the WebDriver instance has been shut down. It is passed the exit 
  code
* (0 if the tests passed). afterLaunch must return a promise if you 
  want
* asynchronous code to be executed before the program exits.
* This is called only once before the program exits (after onCleanUp).
*/
```